# Unexpected character '@'

Tags: laravel, npm, sass, laravel-5.4

I recently switched to laravel 5.4.

When i tried to run `npm run watch` I get the following error --

[image: Error]

I didn't even done any edit in my sass file.

Sass File looks like this  ---

```
// Fonts
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:300,400,600);

// Variables
@import "variables";

// Bootstrap
@import "node_modules/bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap";
```

How can i solve this?

My `package.json` file looks like this --

```
{
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "node node_modules/cross-env/bin/cross-env.js NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "watch": "node node_modules/cross-env/bin/cross-env.js NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --watch --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "hot": "node node_modules/cross-env/bin/cross-env.js NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --inline --hot --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "production": "node node_modules/cross-env/bin/cross-env.js NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "axios": "^0.15.2",
        "bootstrap-sass": "^3.3.7",
        "jquery": "^3.1.0",
        "laravel-mix": "^0.5.0",
        "less": "^2.7.2",
        "less-loader": "^2.2.3",
        "lodash": "^4.16.2",
        "vue": "^2.0.1"
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you post your `package.json` file?

Comment: @MichaelCurry updated

Comment: Thanks, could you post node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js

Comment: @MichaelCurry it is a very long file. I think it is not allowed to post such a file in stackoverflow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a current issue with Laravel Mix. There is an open issue discussion on GitHub for this.

https://github.com/JeffreyWay/laravel-mix/issues/200

According to the some of the users you could use Laravel Mix version 0.5.8 and your problem would go away. Edit your package.json file to have `"laravel-mix": "0.5.8"`

I recommend using this until the issue is resolved.

This seems to be an issue for windows users.

---

#### Edit

As of this moment the issues seems to have been resolved. You need to pull in the latest version of Mix and also add `"vue-loader": "10.1.0"` to your package.json file.

Comment: Thank You. It helped me.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have sass installed on your computer. If you don't have it installed, instructions are here: http://sass-lang.com/install.

Then you need to make sure `sass` is also installed in the project. Reading your `package.json` it seems you have `less` instead.

Run: `npm i --save-dev sass`

By default your project comes with `less` installed. Locate the file `webpack.mix.js` from the root folder. find the following line

```
mix.less('resources/assets/less/app.less', 'public/css')
```

.less('resources/assets/less/admin.less', 'public/css');

And change it to

```
mix.sass('resources/assets/sass/app.sass', 'public/css')
```

.sass('resources/assets/sass/admin.sass', 'public/css/admin');

If you don't see those exact same lines, find something similar.

Comment: I still get that error. I installed sass on my system and installed sass on my project, but no use

Comment: ok you have got to show what the `watch command does`. My guess is that it's not using sass compiler. Since it came with `less` already installed, I think the watch command is using `less` by default. Try to change it.

Comment: How can I do it? Please guide me

Comment: Updated my answer

Comment: My `webpack.mix.js` file is having sass by default -- [link](https://i.imgur.com/YBzwEPM.png)

Comment: I wish I could help further. But I dont use webpack. I use `gulp` instead. Laravel recently switched to webpack, but I haven't switched yet. Still stuck with `gulp`.

Comment: Same as me I am also new to this. I used gulp before. Today found new things

Comment: Started new project today. Deleted everything and installed gulp instead.